# What Does It Mean When Your Car Won't Start and Your Radio Won't Come On?

Tags: starter

The starter does not engage. The lights, door locks and the dash work.  The radio however does not come on. What could this issue be?

Comment: Could be an almost-empty battery. Do the headlights work? Or are they dim?

Comment: They work and don't dim. The starter doesn't even engage. The radio is the only otger thing that wont work.

Answer (score 2):

Your "always on" electricals (headlights, dashlights and power locks) are working, so you have *some* battery power. Since your "key on" electricals aren't working (radio, starter, and check your heater fan, I bet it won't come on either), it's likely to be the ignition switch.

Shoot us your make and model, we can help you diagnose the ignition switch.

Comment: +1 I agree with this gut reaction. My 97 Blazer (i.e. 95-03 era GM ignition components) has needed two ignition switch replacements and these symptoms ring true. Curiously...the second time it failed...my spare key actually worked for awhile after it quit working for my main key. Even weirder, if I wiggled the key a little as I inserted it I could usually get it to catch. But over time this became unreliable until I inevitably had to replace the switch. So OP might want to test their spare key...esp if it's an older model GM.

Answer (score -1):

Could still be the battery. Do you have a multimeter? Check the battery voltage. Can you jump start the car? If yes->battery problem. No->starter is broken.

Comment: Unless the ignition switch is faulty.

Comment: True. But then I'd expect both the dash and the radio to work instead of just one of them.

Comment: Depends which circuit they are wired into.

Answer (score -2):

The issue is with the battery.check the connection to ensure it is not loose connection.If it is not then u have to get your battery checked.it might just need an external power-up